# How to deal with trend of independent variables in panel data regression? (if differencing does not work)

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, stationarity

I am running a pooled OLS regression on the following model:

[image]

Running this regression results in the following results:

[image]

The R-squared seems so high that I get the suspicion that something goes wrong. I, therefore, looked at non-stationarity of the individual variables and most of them pose non-stationary time series. To account for this I tried differencing but then the adjusted-R-squared dropped to 0.06. Furthermore, I read in Baltagi, B. H., & Baltagi, B. H. (2008), that non-stationarity is not such a problem in micro panels which is the case as the number of firms (N) is equal to 1729 whereas the average length of the time series (T) is 8.

I also tried to run a fixed-effects model but this gives me the same output as pooled OLS.

I do think that all variables are likely to pose a trend so I am wondering how I should account for this? As I said earlier differencing did not improve anything, so I am now thinking of trying to detrend all-time series by model fitting or maybe to run a Generalized least squares instead. However, I am not specialised in this field so I hope that there is anyone that can point me in the right direction.